# FInd the activity name of an Android APK for appium

Tags: java, appium

I need to get the Activity name of an Android APK. I have tried appium GUI and used the same but error is coming while running the code that " application cannot be launched as the activity is not correct".

So i want to know how to look for the correct activity so that i can easily code scripts for other applications as well.
I am using appium server V-1.7 and java client-V5.0

Answer (score 2):

I used to do it like this:

```
adb pm list packages -f | grep "any_filter"
```

Last command will display a list of every package installer that contains "any_filter"

Example of packages (a few from my real device):

```
com.adobe.reader
com.teamviewer.host.samsung
com.whatsapp
```

And once you got the package of that app. To get the Activity for each app:

```
adb pm dump com.adobe.reader | grep -A 1 MAIN
adb pm dump com.teamviewer.host.samsung | grep -A 1 MAIN
adb pm dump com.whatsapp | grep -A 1 MAIN
```

You will find out that it might have a few Activities... You will have to try, but you can figure out wich one is by their names...

Hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

We have to use **android decompiler** for it.

Try below link

http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk

Steps to follow:

```
1. Choose correct .apk file from your system.

2. Upload and Decompile apk.

3. After sometime apk will be decompile and you will get source code of
it.


4. Refer AndroidMenifest.xml file and find launcher tag in menifest,
And mention activity which using this tag is the activity you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get activities from apk with the `aapt` command

```
aapt list -a /path/to/your/apk | sed -n '/ activity /{:loop n;s/^.*android:name.*="\([^"]\{1,\}\)".*/\1/;T loop;p;t}'
```

and get the package name with following command

```
aapt dump badging /path/to/your/apk | sed -n "/package: name=/{s/.*package: name='\([^\']\{1,\}\)'.*/\1/;p}"
```

Once your have the package name and activity name, and the activity has exported attribute set, you can start activity with the following command.

```
$ adb shell am start -n '<package-name>/<activitiy>'
```

Comment: activity command is not working, error coming 'sed' is not recognized as an internal or external command. help to share exact command for appium testing, and i am using windows OS

Answer (score 0):

There is also an option to open you app in the device and run command via command line:
`adb shell "dumpsys window windows | grep –E 'mCurrentFocus'"`

With this command you can get current activity of the running app.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your device /emulator is connected.
You can verify the connectivity by typing adb devices in command line .
open your app in the device and run  below command via command line.

```
adb shell "dumpsys window windows | grep –E 'mCurrentFocus'"
```

With above command you can get package name follows with current activity of the running app
Package name/ App activity.

```
// Set your application's appPackage
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");
        // Set your application's AppActivity
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
```

Other option is using uiautomatorviewer, open the app in emulator or device and using uiautomatorviewer you can get the values .