# Appium fails to launch on Android emulator with multiple activities

Tags: java, android, gradle, automation, appium-android

I'm using

- Appium v1.22.2
- IntelliJ community
- Gradle with dependencies
  implementation 'io.appium:java-client:7.6.0'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
  implementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.22.0'

Can you please help me to start an application via Appium on Android Emulator with multiple activities?

I couldn't get ahold of the concept of *App_Wait_Activity* and was trying to find the best suitable activity. While looking at Appium logs, it says that appium found the best match which is *presentation.onboarding.OnboardActivity*. When I choose this activity the application launches and quits, and there are errors. (See the error log below)

I also checked AndroidManifest.xml on Android Studio and there are multiple activities coming from top to bottom as:

1. android:name=".presentation.splash.StartActivity"
2. android:name=".presentation.onboarding.OnboardActivity"
3. android:name=".presentation.splash.SplashActivity"
4. android:name=".MainActivity"
5. android:name=".presentation.custom_view.widgets.WidgetsActivity"

The error log with chosen *App_activity as .presentation.onboarding.OnboardActivity*.

https://res.cloudinary.com/newslettergs/image/upload/v1657776487/Screen_Shot_2022-07-14_at_11.25.13_diutcy.png

```
    org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'app_package_name' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command '/Users/baizhan/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am start -W -n app_package_name/app_package_name.presentation.onboarding.OnboardActivity -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000' exited with code 255'; Command output: Security exception: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=app_package_name/.presentation.onboarding.OnboardActivity } from null (pid=10838, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10151

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=app_package_name/.presentation.onboarding.OnboardActivity } from null (pid=10838, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10151
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPermission(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1043)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:760)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:583)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1288)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:514)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAndWait(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1231)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAndWait(ActivityManagerService.java:3512)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.runStartActivity(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:513)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.onCommand(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:172)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:104)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onShellCommand(ActivityManagerService.java:9774)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:881)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:765)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:4498)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2741)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to see `automationName` in your capabilities. You can follow [this](https://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/android-uiautomator2/) guide.

You can also follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59358991/3879644) to setup your `appActivity` or `appWaitActivity`

Comment: Thank you for the response! Have just added the automationName as "UiAutomator2". Still not launching ((

Comment: @bonzdho_01 Have you tried to check the main activity and updated it?

Comment: Also, getting this error in appium log:
`Got response with status 404: {"sessionId":"ce4d4e60-4e1e-4dce-b648-868c3a65cf5d","value":{"error":"invalid session id","message":"The session identified by ce4d4e60-4e1e-4dce-b648-868c3a65cf5d is not `
`Matched W3C error code 'invalid session id' to NoSuchDriverError`

Comment: Yes, I checked via appium log and it shows this:

`Running '/Users/baizhan/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am start -W -n com.app/con.app.presentation.splash.StartActivity -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000'`